# How to access AppDelegate methods in react native iOS module

Tags: javascript, swift, objective-c, react-native

I'm building an iOS module and want to hook into the AppDelegate methods like `applicationWillResignActive`, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the javascript tag for?

Comment: Because it's React Native, it's still JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive) that method will be fired every time the application will enter the background.

You can achieve that in react native by using [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)
that can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.

**Example:**

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppState, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const AppStateExample = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log("AppState", appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Current state is: {appStateVisible}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default AppStateExample;
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to do it in native Objective-C code?

Comment: Yes you can using native modules, see https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios

Comment: Yes but I can't access these methods inside of my module, that's the whole question actually

Comment: Why you cant access it ? what you did and what was the result please clarify your question.

Comment: In native modules you can't hook into thing like applicationWillResignActive and the methods in AppDelegate, I'm looking for a workaround or something

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618433/how-do-you-properly-emit-and-receive-an-event-from-a-bridged-ios-module-to-javas answer your question ?